# How to create a subdomain using a script

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain, script

How can one create a new subdomain using a script? Creating a new database or database table is something I'm familiar with.

If this is not possible, how does [About.com](http://www.about.com) create all the subdomains they use. Is it manually, or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by subdomain? Just the entry in the DNS System or the whole handling of the subdomain (which is just a hostname).

You can set a wildcard DNS entry so every `hostname.yourdomain.com` is set to your webserver e.g.:

`*.example.com IN A 123.123.123.123`

so `everything.example.org` would be resolved to `123.123.123.123` except you specified a entry for the URL.

Your Apache vhost needs to accept every hostname of the domain

`ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com`

Everything else is handled by *.htaccess* files using `mod_rewrite` and PHP routers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel you can use the xmlapi class https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php.

You then invoke it like this:

```
 require("xmlapi.php"); // this can be downloaded from https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php/blob/master/xmlapi.php
$xmlapi = new xmlapi("your-primary-domain.com");   
$xmlapi->set_port( 2083 );   
$xmlapi->password_auth('username','password');   //cpanel credentials 
$xmlapi->set_debug(0);//output actions in the error log 1 for true and 0 false 

// create subdomain
print $xmlapi->api1_query('accountname','SubDomain','addsubdomain',array('subdomain.domain.com',0,0,'/public_html/location.of.the.web.files'));
```